# what is the command to make Mathematica beep each time there is an error even for the same command?

Tags: configuration

sorry for a basic question, but does any one know what is the trick to make the front end beep at me each time I issue the same command (which contain an error)?

It now only beeps the first time, but when I SHIFT+ENTER the same command again, it stops beeping. I want it to beep each time.

here is an example:

```
expr = 0.09 - (0.00043739999999999995*
     Sin[x])/(Sqrt[1 - 0.36*Sin[x]^2]*(0.0225 - 0.0081*Sin[x]^2))
FullSimplify[expr]
```

now it beeped and gave message to the notebook

```
Indeterminate
```

and the following messages to the console:

```
 Mathematica beeped to let you know that a warning or error 
 message was generated by the kernel. You can disable this beep by resetting 
 MessageOptions in the Option Inspector.
```

But when I typed the above again:

```
FullSimplify[expr]
```

I see no more messages to the console and no more beeps but only the  `Indeterminate` message comes out to the notebook. Only way to see the error again and hear the beeps is to do `Remove["Global`*"]` and run everything again.

Strange thing, is that this behaviour does not happen for everything. For example, if I type

```
Simplify[1/0]
```

I will see a new error a hear a new beep EACH time I execute the command. I have a feeling that the kernel is remembering things. But I do not want to clear everything each time.

I am using 8.04, and this is a picture of my setup:

[image]

and here is the messageOptions in the advanced setup

[image]

I tried to change the `MaxMessageCount` to 100 but no change. same for the `MessageCountRestTime`.

thanks

Comment: Try using `SetDelayed` (`expr := (* stuff *)`) instead of `Set` (`expr = (* stuff *)`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Heike figured out what was going on](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/340/34). 
However, if you want a command that will make your `Simplify[expr]` beep everytime, you need to turn of the symbolic part of the cache using

```
SetSystemOptions["CacheOptions" -> {"Symbolic" -> False}]
```

Comment: @Nasser: Of course, this will slow down some calculations. It will also make some of the weird behaviour go away, like trying the same integral twice in a row and getting two different results!

Answer (score 4):

I think you only get the warning once because `Simplify` somehow remembers which expressions it has simplified before. For example, in a new session this only gives me a warning for the first evaluation of `FullSimplify`:

```
FullSimplify[1/x, x == 0]
FullSimplify[1/x, x == 0]
```

output:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now if I clear `Simplify` and run `FullSimplify` again the warning show up again

```
Unprotect[Simplify]
Clear[Simplify]
Protect[Simplify]
FullSimplify[1/x, x == 0]
```

output:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: +1: Although, to clear the cached simplify results you should use [`ClearSystemCache[]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ClearSystemCache.html) or `ClearSystemCache["Symbolic"]`.

Comment: @Simon Thanks. I knew there was a different command to do this, but I couldn't find it.